# Object in Datatable type

Tags: asp.net, arrays, sql-server, jpeg

I have a SQL Server database with 3 columns, 2 of which are strings and 1 is a jpeg. The image is stored as `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

[image: sql image]

I have saved this data to a DataTable in ASP.NET. I want to have the image as a byte array but apparently it is type object.... or is it?

[image]

What is `dt.rows[0 ][2 ],` an object or a byte array? If it's not a byte array, why does `.ToString()` return `System.Byte[]`?

My index controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-896D683;Initial Catalog=aspdb1;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(" select * from stuff_for_carrousel ", con);

    List<front_page> mi_list = new List<front_page>();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    Image newImage = mi_converter.convert_to_image(dt.Rows[0][2]);

    ViewData["dd"] = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    ViewData["ccc"] = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    ViewData["ts"] = dt.Rows[0][2].GetType().ToString();

    return View();
}
```

My converter

```
    public class mi_converter
    {
        public Image convert_to_image(byte[] b)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(b))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I just need to convert `dt.rows[0][2]` to a byte array.

Comment: `image` has been deprecated since 2005; you should ***really*** be using `varbinary(MAX)` by now.

Comment: it is varbinary i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

`dt.Rows[0][0]` means: Get me the value of the first column of the first row.
Since that value could basically be anything, the .Net framework can only represent it as `System.Object`.

Your method, however, expects a `byte[]` - so you need to cast that object to a byte array, or better yet, use the [`Field<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataRowExtensions_Field__1_System_Data_DataRow_System_Int32_) extension method instead of the indexer:

```
Image newImage = mi_converter.convert_to_image(dt.Rows[0].Field<Byte[]>(2));
```

And some notes as well:

1. Using `select *` is a bad idea - it makes your code vulnerable to changes in the table.
2. using the ordinal indexer (0, 1, 2) is even worst, since now your code is even more vulnerable to changes in the table.
3. using identifiers such as `"dd"`, `"ccc"` or any other meaningless combinations of letters in your code is a terrible idea - **always** use meaningful names. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: More likely - someone else in the future will thank you.